# What do these Xcursor names mean?

Tags: x11, xcursor

I have a plan to make my own Xcursor theme. I'm looking at existing themes and found some strange names such as `08e8e1c95fe2fc01f976f1e063a24ccd`. I found a piece of code that contain this name.

https://vimsky.com/examples/detail/cpp-ex---QHash-reserve-method.html

According to the comment, it seems to be an MD5 hash of something hardcoded. But I failed to produce this hash. Which programs need these names? All the themes installed on my system are symbolic links to these names, but I can't find any documentation for this.

And there are two cursors named `size_bdiag` for top-right/bottom-left window resizing and `size_fdiag` for top-left/bottom-right window resizing. But I failed to understand what these names mean. Maybe 'diag' means 'diagonal' but still I can't guess what 'b' and 'f' mean. I googled several times but I can't find any documentation. Do those have no meaning? Is the original author just playing with me?

Comment: Forward diagonal (like `/`) and backward diagonal (like ``\``), I guess?

Answer (score 2):

The [manual page](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xcursor/xcursor.html) explains how hashing is used:

```
void XcursorImageHash (
               XImage                *image,
               unsigned char          hash[XCURSOR_BITMAP_HASH_SIZE])

       Compute  a  hash  of  the image, to display when the environment
       variable XCURSOR_DISCOVER is set.
```

and

```
Cursor XcursorTryShapeBitmapCursor (
               Display               *dpy,
               Pixmap                 source,
               Pixmap                 mask,
               XColor                *foreground,
               XColor                *background,
               unsigned int           x,
               unsigned int           y)

      If the display supports either ARGB or themes,  try  to  load  a
      cursor  into  Xcursor's  cache  using  the source parameter as a
      Pixmap-id.  The source may no longer be in the  cache.   Xcursor
      uses the hash value to identify the desired image.
```

The [source-code](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/lib/libxcursor/-/blob/master/src/xlib.c#L280) explains that it does not use md5, etc.,

```
    /*
     * Compute the hash.  Yes, it might be nice to use
     * a stronger hash function, but MD5 and SHA1 are both
     * a bit to expensive in time and space for this,
     * and cursors are generally small enough that a weak
     * hash is sufficient to distinguish among them.
     */
```

Regarding the obscure mnemonics, [*Fun with X mouse cursors, specifically left_ptr_watch*](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/x_cursors/) has some illustrations:

- "fdiag" is a backslash-like symbol with arrow-heads
- "bdiag" is a forward-slash-like symbol with arrow-heads

However, that's just one set of images.  The X cursor names (defined in a [header file](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/lib/libx11/-/blob/master/include/X11/cursorfont.h)) are used in the Xcursor API for various sets of images; some are completely unrelated to the original X cursor pictures.  For instance, bdiag/fdiag appear to be Qt names, which in turn may be mapped to the X names (*ymmv* - reading the Qt source code would help):

- `Qt::SizeBDiagCursor` to `BOTTOM_LEFT_CORNER`
- `Qt::SizeFDiagCursor` to `BOTTOM_RIGHT_CORNER`

Those names on the right correspond to the definitions in the X source code:

```
#define XC_bottom_left_corner 12
#define XC_bottom_right_corner 14
```

Determining ***where*** the bdiag/fdiag names came from would require some research.  The Qt developers may recall, but then again, maybe not.  This [*QCursor Class Reference*](https://het.as.utexas.edu/HET/Software/PyQt/qcursor.html) refers to names such as `ibeam` (which does not exist in the X source, but may have come from XView as an equivalent to **`xterm`**).  The xterm [manual page](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:pointerShape) has a list of the X cursor names, without mentioning "ibeam".